# Flash Texture Mapped Triangles look horrible

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, papervision3d

I have a 3D cube made with PaperVision3D.

Each "side" is made of 2 triangles.

I have a different texture "material" mapped to each side.

When I rotate the cube the texture is skewed like '/\' an upside down v between both triangles.  When looking at a face straight on it looks ok but start to rotate and it starts to skew the textures.

How do you make texture mapping in Flash look like DirectX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PaperVision3D doesn't use "real" 3d texturing, it uses [something called affine mapping](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_video_3d_02.html) which is a hack.
In order to achieve better results you need to partition your cube to as many triangles as possible instead of using just two triangles per face.

Comment: To expand on what "affine mapping", it means that each individual triangle of texture is transformed using only affine transformations (rotations and scale transformations), as opposed to perspective transformations (i.e. distortion). With small triangles the difference comes out in the wash.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I was using 2 poly's to each plane. I upped it to 4 and it looks great - no skewing on the edges and the least amount of polygons I can have before I see the scewing again.